# htaccess - Block access to a directory but allow access to files in a specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my server I have folder called `customers`, in which it contains sub-folders `[uid]` (`/customers/[uid]`) where `uid` is the unique identifier assigned to each customer. There are other folders in each `/customers/[uid]`.

Among them there is a folder titled `images` which, as the name suggests, contains images.

I would like to configure the .htaccess so that the user can only access directly files in the `/customers/[uid]/images` but the user is not allowed to access any other folder or any directory listing.

Because I am not very familiar with .htaccess syntax, I tried to search some answers online but I am still very confused. Especially giving that I have already a `RewriteRule` in my `.htaccess`. I am not sure where and how to add more to accomplish what I want.

This is what my `.htaccess` look like for now.

```
DirectoryIndex test.php
<Files "database.ini">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I am using a VPS hosting, and the directory index is , by default, enabled. So now if I try to access `/customers/user` it will give me a list of folders where I can continue to access other folders and files

I have tried putting `Options -Indexes` inside the `<IfModule>`. After that, I indeed cannot access other directories, but I can't access any files in any directory anymore.

Comment: It makes no sense that you should not be able to access files any more, just because you turned directory indexing off.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you mean by _“but the user is not allowed to access any other folder”_? You mean, if my uid was 15, then I should be allowed to access files in `/customers/15/`, but not any other such sub-folder like `/customers/123/`? The server knows nothing of your “uid” at this point.

Comment: Yes so with your example if you try to type /customers/15 or any subfolder, the server will deny your access. However, you can access, for example /customers/15/logo.png, or /customers/15/download.pdf (But not /customers/123/download.pdf neither)

Comment: Well the first one would simply be a case of turning directory indexing off. What problem you said you were having with this preventing access to _files_, is unclear. _“But not /customers/123/download.pdf neither”_ - when you say `uid`, you mean some arbitrary ID you created, right? You are not talking about any system user id on the OS level? If the web server knows nothing of this uid, then this won’t be possible using .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you an do is make a .htaccess file per every user directory and inside it allow access to ./images
So you will have

```
/customers/[uid1]/.htaccess
/customers/[uid2]/.htaccess
```

... etc

and inside every .htaccess you will have:

```
Allow from all
```

Comment: By indicating this, will it block access for other folders? (Since I only indicate that ./images is allowed without mentioning if access to other folders are denied)

Comment: Also, because a new folder will be generated every time there is a new customer. So is this really the best way to do (That I need to be able to generate a new .htaccess everytime). It would be better if I can do that with the .htaccess in the root folder

Comment: Also, I notice that by putting <Directory> ... </Directory> it gives me 500 internal sever error

Comment: Yes just put 
Allow from all
without the <Directory> </Directory> clause
You can block access to other folders from the main .htaccess file

generating .htaccess file per user directory is the easiest way and it wont take much space as it would have just 1 line